# What's the real effect of Luck attribute in Oblivion?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I have played Elder Scrolls Oblivion for almost three years now with different characters and styles. Of all attributes Luck is the least important to me, I barely care about it because I feel is has 0 effect on the game. I have read in UESP and lots of game guides and walkthroughs about this particular attribute and how it affects "every action" in the game. But I don't think so, or at least I am not aware of its influence.

I know from wikis and guides that the higher your Luck: repair hammers break less times, you are most likely to success in stealing or picking locks, the loot on dungeons gets better. Cool stuff, but I can get as many repair hammers as I want (is easy to earn money in this game, c'mon), once I reach level 10 I always get Nocturnal's key (lockpicks ajaja, what are those?) and so.

I recently finished Fallout 1 and 2 and boy, now that is a game where you need Luck as an attribute! I had Luck 9 which meant more chances of performing crittical damage, less random encounters with enemies and more random encounters with merchants or loot, also mixed with Gambling I got lots of money in casinos.See my point? In those games Luck had a real influence in the gameplay.

So, could anyone explain me what's the point of leveling Luck in Oblivion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've read the guides, but you just don't believe them?

Comment: I played about 2000+ hours Oblivion and Luck does exactly what the guide describes. Luck DOES make a difference, just not as much as you'd like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luck is represented differently in every rpg, particularly in the various Bethesda rpgs. Luck as an attribute just isn't weighted as heavily in Oblivion as in other elder scrolls titles. Morrowind for example puts a lot more emphasis on luck because it is related to hit and dodge chance, where Oblivion uses hitbox detection instead. One significant difference that luck provides is that it works as a skill multiplier for every time skills determine a random outcome. Having higher luck is similar to boosting every one of your skills slightly. Just going by the first few paragraphs of the unofficial elder scrolls wiki article, having 100 luck is the equivalent of boosting ALL of your skills by 20 points. Having luck below 50 will have a detrimental effect on all skills. Skill bonuses are the most noticeable effect that luck has on a character, as it is difficult to measure other effects in game.